# Powemock unable to mock class whose dependent class is not present

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I am using the third party jar file which contains a class A. Class A is depends on the class B but this B class is not present in the jar file. 
I am trying to mock the Class A but getting "NoClassDefFoundError" for the class B.
Is it possible to mock class A here? If yes could you please suggest a way to do it?

Comment: Can you provide your code and the error stacktrace you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Since you wont be using A or B (you will be mocking them) try to feed him a fake class B. Obviously you need to use the same package name as the original B.